# hamburger navbar problems with activation

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I have problems with getting this to work... I watch a tutorial (not old) and followed closely. Can anybody see problems with this code or why it shouldn't work? I have started over multiple times, but the same issue. The burger is there but nothing happens when I click it.
HTML

```
          <ul class="nav__links">
            <li><a class="hvr-reveal hjem" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="hvr-reveal status" href="status.html">WEB Status</a></li>
            <li><a class="hvr-reveal weather" href="#">Weather</a></li>
            <li><a class="hvr-reveal adventure" href="info.html">Adventure</a></li>
          </ul>
        <div class="burger">
          <div class="line1"></div>
          <div class="line2"></div>
          <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

CSS

```
.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
   width: 25px;
   height: 2px;
   background-color: white;
   margin: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav__links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    top: 8vh;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav__links li{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Java Script

```
const navSlide = () => {
   const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
   const nav = document.querySelector('.nav__links');

   burger.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    nav.classlist.toggle('nav-active');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

Answer (score 0):

change the javascript line, the `classList` needs an uppercase L

```js
nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
```

And also, your .nav-active class is not doing anything.

For example, change

```css
.nav-active {
   transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

to

```css
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(10%);
}
```

After you applied the changes you should see the element move left and right on click on the burger.

---

**Just a hint**: As more than 50% of Browser are coming from mobile devices you should write your css using the "mobile first" approach. This means, that you should try to use `min-width` if you really have to use media-queries. For Example:

```
.burger {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .burger {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

but

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .burger {
     display: none;
  }
}
```

So that the mobile version becomes the default and therefore faster.

Comment: thank you for the help, and hints! But still after changes, nothing happens when I click the burger.